# Weekly customer count in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a customer dimension:

```
Dimcust

| Custnum | StartDate | EndDate |
```

I want to make a new table, using DAX, that for every week in the last year counts the number of customers (distinct custnum) for each week (meaning that the startdate < week and enddate is null or enddate > week).

However I cant get this to work whatsoever.

What I've tried is the following:

```
Active Users = Calculate(COUNTROWS(filter(DimCustomer; DimCustomer[StartDate].[Date] > WeeklyKPI[Date];DimCustomer[StartDate].[Date] < WeeklyKPI[Date])))
```

This gave the error:

```
A single value for column 'Date' in table 'WeeklyKPI' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result.
```

Where WeeklyKPI[Date] is a date table with each date in the range I want. If this had worked I've would done the same, just with weeknumbers.

What I want:

```
Weeknumber | Number of customers
     1                13,430
     2                32,530
```

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the error because you tried to compare individual values (`DimCustomer[StartDate].[Date]`) with multiple (`WeeklyKPI[Date]`).

If `WeeklyKPI[Date]` has all days of the selected week, you could change your measure to the following:

```
Active Users = Calculate(COUNTROWS(filter(DimCustomer; 
  DimCustomer[StartDate].[Date] > MIN(WeeklyKPI[Date]);
  DimCustomer[StartDate].[Date] < MAX(WeeklyKPI[Date]))))
```

Another option is to create a table with week numbers, `WeekNum(Num)`, and allow the user to select a single value. Your measure would then change to

```
Active Users = Calculate(COUNTROWS(filter(DimCustomer; 
  WEEKNUM(DimCustomer[StartDate].[Date], 2) = FIRSTNONBLANK(WeekNum[Num]))))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've updated the main questin because your solution only gives me one number for the number of customers, however I want the number of customers for each week in a time period. Isn't this possible?

Comment: Plot it against the date table/column (i e `WeekNum[Num]`) and you will see multiple values. Read https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-tutorial-create-measures/